# Prolog Comparisation problem

Tags: prolog

anyone have idea how to solve this problem

counts the number of occurrences of an operator inside an expression. For instance, the query:

```
?- count(a+b*c-(2+3*4)/(5*(2+a)+(b+c)^f((d-e)*(x-y))), *, C).
```

would count the number of occurrences of operator * in the expression given as the first argument and output on C

I am using SWI-prolog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this homework?

Here's some hints:

- Prolog operators are syntactic sugar around normal prolog terms. The expression `3 * 2 + 1` is parsed as the term `'+'('*'(3,2),1)`.
- The built-in predicate `=..` decomposes a term into a list, the head of which is the functor and the tail of which comprises the [non-decomposed] terms that are the arguments to the original term.
- The built-in predicate `functor/3` unifies a term with its functor and arity.
- You might also want to look at `arg/3` which provide the means to examine the arguments of the specified term by ordinal position.

Now that you know that, a fairly simple recursive solution should present itself. If you need to factor in the arity of the desired operator, it's a little more convoluted (but not much).